# Dovecot doesn't fetch mail from Postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have installed Postfix on remote machine that successfully sends emails as well as receives. In order to connect to that remote server through email client (Thunderbird) I have installed Dovecot. Now I can connect to remote server through Thunderbird and even send mails, but cannot receive anything. When I check my Dovecot directories for virtual email users their cur and new directories are empty. Do you have any ideas why?

## **Dovecot configuration:**

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    #port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    #port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0666
     user = postfix
     group = postfix
  }
}

service auth {

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user=postfix
    group=postfix
  }
}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
#!include auth-system.conf.ext
#!include auth-sql.conf.ext   
#!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
#!include auth-checkpassword.conf.ext
#!include auth-vpopmail.conf.ext
#!include auth-static.conf.ext
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-passwdfile.conf.ext:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=PLAIN username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/dovecot-users
}

userdb {
  driver = static
#  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/dovecot-users
args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n

  # Default fields that can be overridden by passwd-file
  #default_fields = quota_rule=*:storage=1G

  # Override fields from passwd-file
  #override_fields = home=/home/virtual/%u
}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf:

```
# SSL/TLS support: yes, no, required. <doc/wiki/SSL.txt>
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
```

postconf -n:

```
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 23: overriding earlier entry: smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 24: overriding earlier entry: smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = theresults.ru, 31143.simplecloud.club, localhost.simplecloud.club, localhost
myhostname = mail.theresults.ru
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: You need to configure Postfix to deliver the mail to Dovecot, not the other way around.

Comment: Here's my idea: Some part of your configuration is wrong. If you want help figuring out which part, you need to include it in your question.

Comment: @JennyD, added.

Comment: Perhaps there are misconfiguration between postfix and dovecot, show the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: What do the logs of postfix and dovecot say about message retrieval / delivery?